# How to save audio videocall file to server using jQuery and PHP and Agora

Tags: php, jquery

I am working with Agora Basic Video call ([see the sample](https://github.com/AgoraIO/API-Examples-Web/tree/main/Demo/basicVideoCall)) and everything is working fine.

Now I want to save the recorded audio/Video call to server as user is leaving or click on a button using jQuery and PHP.

Here is my jQuery/AJAX approach:

```
          //$(function () {
               // $('#save').click(function () {
                   
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('video', user.videoTrack.play);
                         $.ajax({
                        url: './video.php',
                        data: form_data,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                       crossDomain: true,
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (msg) {
                               
                $('#result').html(msg);
alert('saved');
            

                        }
                    });

     //});
            //});
```

Here is my PHP code approach:

```
<?php
 
if(isset($_FILES["video"])){
    // Define a name for the file
    $fileName = "myvideo.mp4";


    // In this case the current directory of the PHP script
    $uploadDirectory = './'. $fileName;
    
    // Move the file to your server
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"], $uploadDirectory)) {
        echo("Couldn't upload video !");
    }
}else{
    echo "No file uploaded";
}
 
?>
```

Here is Agora Sample code called `basicVideoCall.js` which does the video call:

```
/*
 *  These procedures use Agora Video Call SDK for Web to enable local and remote
 *  users to join and leave a Video Call channel managed by Agora Platform.
 */

/*
 *  Create an {@link https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartcclient.html|AgoraRTCClient} instance.
 *
 * @param {string} mode - The {@link https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/clientconfig.html#mode| streaming algorithm} used by Agora SDK.
 * @param  {string} codec - The {@link https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/clientconfig.html#codec| client codec} used by the browser.
 */
var client = AgoraRTC.createClient({ mode: "rtc", codec: "vp8" });

/*
 * Clear the video and audio tracks used by `client` on initiation.
 */
var localTracks = {
  videoTrack: null,
  audioTrack: null
};

/*
 * On initiation no users are connected.
 */
var remoteUsers = {};

/*
 * On initiation. `client` is not attached to any project or channel for any specific user.
 */
var options = {
  appid: null,
  channel: null,
  uid: null,
  token: null
};

/*
 * When this page is called with parameters in the URL, this procedure
 * attempts to join a Video Call channel using those parameters.
 */
$(() => {
  var urlParams = new URL(location.href).searchParams;
  options.appid = urlParams.get("appid");
  options.channel = urlParams.get("channel");
  options.token = urlParams.get("token");
  options.uid = urlParams.get("uid");
  if (options.appid && options.channel) {
    $("#uid").val(options.uid);
    $("#appid").val(options.appid);
    $("#token").val(options.token);
    $("#channel").val(options.channel);
    $("#join-form").submit();
  }
})

/*
 * When a user clicks Join or Leave in the HTML form, this procedure gathers the information
 * entered in the form and calls join asynchronously. The UI is updated to match the options entered
 * by the user.
 */
$("#join-form").submit(async function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#join").attr("disabled", true);
  try {
    options.appid = $("#appid").val();
    options.token = $("#token").val();
    options.channel = $("#channel").val();
    options.uid = Number($("#uid").val());
    await join();
    if(options.token) {
      $("#success-alert-with-token").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $("#success-alert a").attr("href", `index.html?appid=${options.appid}&channel=${options.channel}&token=${options.token}`);
      $("#success-alert").css("display", "block");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    $("#leave").attr("disabled", false);
  }
})

/*
 * Called when a user clicks Leave in order to exit a channel.
 */
$("#leave").click(function (e) {
  leave();
})

/*
 * Join a channel, then create local video and audio tracks and publish them to the channel.
 */
async function join() {

  // Add an event listener to play remote tracks when remote user publishes.
  client.on("user-published", handleUserPublished);
  client.on("user-unpublished", handleUserUnpublished);

  // Join a channel and create local tracks. Best practice is to use Promise.all and run them concurrently.
  [ options.uid, localTracks.audioTrack, localTracks.videoTrack ] = await Promise.all([
    // Join the channel.
    client.join(options.appid, options.channel, options.token || null, options.uid || null),
    // Create tracks to the local microphone and camera.
    AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack(),
    AgoraRTC.createCameraVideoTrack()
  ]);

  // Play the local video track to the local browser and update the UI with the user ID.
  localTracks.videoTrack.play("local-player");
  $("#local-player-name").text(`localVideo(${options.uid})`);

  // Publish the local video and audio tracks to the channel.
  await client.publish(Object.values(localTracks));
  console.log("publish success");
}

/*
 * Stop all local and remote tracks then leave the channel.
 */
async function leave() {
  for (trackName in localTracks) {
    var track = localTracks[trackName];
    if(track) {
      track.stop();
      track.close();
      localTracks[trackName] = undefined;

    }
  }

  // Remove remote users and player views.
  remoteUsers = {};
  $("#remote-playerlist").html("");

  // leave the channel
  await client.leave();

  $("#local-player-name").text("");
  $("#join").attr("disabled", false);
  $("#leave").attr("disabled", true);
  console.log("client leaves channel success");
}


/*
 * Add the local use to a remote channel.
 *
 * @param  {IAgoraRTCRemoteUser} user - The {@link  https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartcremoteuser.html| remote user} to add.
 * @param {trackMediaType - The {@link https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/itrack.html#trackmediatype | media type} to add.
 */
async function subscribe(user, mediaType) {
  const uid = user.uid;
  // subscribe to a remote user
  await client.subscribe(user, mediaType);
  console.log("subscribe success");
  if (mediaType === 'video') {
    const player = $(`
      <div id="player-wrapper-${uid}">
        <p class="player-name">remoteUser(${uid})</p>
        <div id="player-${uid}" class="player"></div>
      </div>
    `);
    $("#remote-playerlist").append(player);
    user.videoTrack.play(`player-${uid}`);

  }
  if (mediaType === 'audio') {
    user.audioTrack.play();
  }
}

/*
 * Add a user who has subscribed to the live channel to the local interface.
 *
 * @param  {IAgoraRTCRemoteUser} user - The {@link  https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartcremoteuser.html| remote user} to add.
 * @param {trackMediaType - The {@link https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/itrack.html#trackmediatype | media type} to add.
 */
function handleUserPublished(user, mediaType) {
  const id = user.uid;
  remoteUsers[id] = user;
  subscribe(user, mediaType);
}

/*
 * Remove the user specified from the channel in the local interface.
 *
 * @param  {string} user - The {@link  https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartcremoteuser.html| remote user} to remove.
 */
function handleUserUnpublished(user, mediaType) {
  if (mediaType === 'video') {
    const id = user.uid;
    delete remoteUsers[id];
    $(`#player-wrapper-${id}`).remove();

  }
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: You will have to look at the Agora docs to see what to call to switch on a recording mode (assuming it supports that). You probably will want to see how to make that legal in your jurisdiction also.

Comment: agora supports recording, there are 3 ways you can record your video, check this url
https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/product_cloud_recording?platform=RESTful